# Docker - Container IP addresses mapping

Tags: docker, mapping, ip-address

In Docker, I have 3 containers which are node, mysql and redis. When I run `sudo iptables -t nat -L -n` I can see those containers are running on different IP addresses like below

[image]

However, the IP addresses order for the services and the IP addresses (on some machine it's `172.23.0.x`, on some machine it's `172.21.0.x`) might be different every time I do `docker-compose up --build` so if I want the app works, I gotta config IP addresses for each service manually. Is there any way I can automatically map a fixed IP address for each service in the `docker-compose.yml` file? Thanks. Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  universe:
    build: .
    working_dir: /usr/src
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
      - /usr/src/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always

  # Redis Alpine
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"

  # MySQL 5.7
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
      MYSQL_USER: database_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: database_password
    volumes:
    - /config/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
```

Comment: Don't post information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this type of docker-compose.yml configuration with defining a network with bridge connection including **subnet** and **gateway** for that defined network.

```
version: "3"
services:
  universe:
    build: .
    working_dir: /usr/src
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
      - /usr/src/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.3.0.2

  # Redis Alpine
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.3.0.3

  # MySQL 5.7
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
      MYSQL_USER: database_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: database_password
    volumes:
    - /config/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.3.0.4

networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.3.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.3.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks. It works without the last line (`gateway`). I got `networks.vpcbr.ipam.config value Additional properties are not allowed ('gateway' was unexpected)` if the last line there. What is the purpose of using `10.3.0.x`? Can I change that to localhost (`127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Well, changing `docker-compose` to version 2 would make `gateway` work

Comment: @TriNguyen you cant use localhost ip address in this case.generally we use 172.0.0.0 private range ip address as well as 10.0.0.0 private ip range to work with private networks in docker environment.

Comment: None of this configuration is necessary.  Out of the box Docker Compose will create a Docker network for you and you can communicate between containers by DNS name.  You can not use this configuration to make `localhost` or 127.0.0.1 mean something different (it _always_ means “this container” in a Docker context).

Answer (score 1):

In your Docker Compose setup as you’ve shown it, to communicate between containers, you can use the names of the services (`universe`, `redis`, `mysql`) as ordinary host names and they’ll resolve to the internal IP address of the container, whatever it happens to be.

Note that if you’re using the `ports:` option to remap a published port, you still need to connect to the *internal* port (the one on the right side of the colon).  For instance you’d connect to `mysql:3306` even if you specified a different external port mapping or not port mapping at all.

This doesn’t work from outside of Docker space; there you connect to the host’s DNS name or IP address with the published `ports:`, and the fact of Docker is totally hidden from you.